# Xpath to retrieve a node's text value

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<parent>
  <Children>
     <child name='Child_1'>Child1_Value</child>
     <child name='Child_2'>Child2_Value</child>
     <child name='Child_3'>Child3_Value</child>
     <child name='Child_4'>Child4_Value</child>
   </Children>
 </parent>
```

In the above structure, How do we get the value of Child1,2,3,4 attribute values ie. Child1_Value, Child2_Value so on using XPATH without using String or Data functions.
Any help is much appreciated

I am using the below Xpath, but I am returned with a True value

```
/parent/Children/child[@name="Child_1"]
```

Comment: Why can't you use string or data functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value (text node) of the `child` element, try adding `text()`...

```
/parent/Children/child[@name="Child_1"]/text()
```